# d3 select from angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg

I have a directive in angular 1.x, in which I instatiate d3 pie chart. I want to add some text to it so in link function I wrote:

```
 var svg = d3.select(element).selectAll('svg');
 var donut = svg.selectAll('g.nv-slice').filter(
                                    function (d, i) {
                                    return i == 0;
                                }
                            );
 donut.insert('text', 'g')
      .text('Line One')
      .attr('class', 'middle')
      .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
      .attr('dy', '-.55em')
      .style('fill', '#000');
```

But I get an error: Uncaught TypeError: n.querySelectorAll is not a function
There is no such error if I get svg as `var svg = d3.select('svg');`, but I want d3 to select only from current directive element

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bnUY9/26/

Comment: what does this console in the link function.
`var svg = d3.select(element).selectAll('svg');
console.log(svg.node())`
another question why `selectAll`
you may have just one svg
`var svg = d3.select(element).select('svg')` please clarify

Comment: `console.log(svg.node())` has no effect because code failes on previous line. I've tried `var svg = d3.select(element).select('svg')` but result was the same

Comment: Ok it would be better if you can provide a fiddle.
what does this print `console.log(d3.select(element).node())` if you put it on the first line of the link function

Comment: The problem is that I want d3 to select `svg` not from document but only from directive element

Comment: console.log(d3.select(element).node()): `[idea-chart-view.query-component__widget.ng-scope.ng-isolate-scope, context: idea-chart-view.query-component__widget.ng-scope.ng-isolate-scope]`

Comment: Well when you do `console.log(d3.select(element).node())` it should have consoled the DOM element or `console.log(d3.select(element).size())` it should have shown 1. but i can see strange array...I think it would be tough without a fiddle I am sorry :(

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bnUY9/22/ here's fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I resolved my problem by using `var selection = d3.selectAll($element);`

http://jsfiddle.net/bnUY9/27/